# Combining two partial derivatives into one partial derivative

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Can someone explain to me why the following is true (from derivation of conservation of mass general equation in fluid mechanics):

$\rho\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} + u\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial (u\rho)}{\partial x}$

I know that the sum rule of differentiation is being used, but I don't understand what happens to the $\rho$ and u coefficients of the partial derivatives.

Thanks.

Comment: Simply the product rule has been applied here.

Comment: It's actually the product rule that's being used here: $$\frac{\partial (u\cdot v)}{\partial x}=v\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+u\cdot\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

Comment: OH! of course, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ayush Khaitan and Dolma explained, this is the product rule. Since there's a chance  that you'll encounter less obvious applications on this rule in PDE, I generalize:

> For any first-order linear differential operator $D=\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}$ (where $\alpha_k$ are smooth functions, possibly matrix-valued if $u$ is vector-valued) we have 
>   $$D(uv)=uDv+vDu\tag1$$

Useful special cases include

1. $D=\partial/\partial z$ and $D=\partial/\partial\bar z$ in complex analysis
2. $Du=\nabla u$ (gradient), $D\mathbf u=\nabla \cdot \mathbf u$ (divergence), and $D\mathbf u=\nabla \times \mathbf u$ (curl)

Sample computation with Laplacian (divergence of gradient): since 
$\nabla(uv)= v\nabla u+u\nabla v$, it follows that $\Delta (uv)=v\Delta u+u\Delta v+2\nabla u\cdot \nabla v$. The product rule is used five times here.